# ''Interacción Fallida'' al ejecutar un comando slash en un bot de discord

Tags: python, discord.py

Cuando ejecuto el bot está online bien, cuando pongo "/" me aparece bien el comando Slash pero cuando lo ejecuto me pone "INTERACCIÓN FALLIDA".
El bot está escrito en Python, y tiene el rol puesto de administrador, tiene todos los permisos posibles en el servidor. También están instaladas las dependencias de Discord.py y Discord Slash.

Este es mi código:

1.**Archivo bot.py:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

initial_extensions = ['cogs.cogs_example']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in initial_extensions:
        bot.load_extension(extension)
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Conectado como {bot.user.name} - {bot.user.id}')
    print('------')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="By:MIDAS_74"))

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send('Comando no encontrado.')
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('Faltan argumentos para el comando.')
    else:
        print(f'Error: {error}')

bot.slash_commands = []

@bot.command(name='saludo', help='Saluda al bot')
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Hola {ctx.author.mention}!')

    bot.slash_commands.append({
        "name": "saludo",
        "description": "Saluda al bot"
    })

@bot.command(name='comandos', help='Lista todos los comandos slash disponibles')
async def list_commands(ctx):
    response = "Comandos disponibles:\n"
    for command in bot.slash_commands:
        response += f"/{command['name']} - {command['description']}\n"
    await ctx.send(response)

bot.run('TOKEN_ID')  # Reemplaza 'TOKEN' con el token de tu bot
```

2.**Archivo cogs.example:**

```
from discord.ext import commands

class CogsExample(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name='cogs_ejemplo', help='Comando de ejemplo en una extensión')
    async def cogs_example_command(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('¡Este es un comando de ejemplo en una extensión!')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(CogsExample(bot))
```